# Table View height changes on tap or when popped back to

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, autosize

I have a table view that loads 3 custom cells.  1 custom cell has an `ImageView` in it, and it seems to be the culprit of the **table view moving when any cell is tapped**.

This is what I've tried, but it hasn't worked.

If I use a static value (i.e. `return 180`) it works just fine, but anything other than that the table view jumps.

Anyone know why?  Thanks!

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    id model = self.Model[indexPath.row];

    if ([model isKindOfClass:[FR self]]) {
        ListTableViewCell *cellOne = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"1Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (!cellOne) {
            cellOne = [[ListTableViewCell alloc] init];

            FR *fD = (FR *)model;
            NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fD.title];
            NSString *dateString = [self timeSincePublished:fD.pubDate];
            NSString *description = [self removeHTMLTags:fD.description];
            NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fD.link];

            cellOne.labelHeadline.text = title;
            cellOne.labelDescription.text = description;
            cellOne.labelPublished.text = dateString;
        }

        // Make sure the cell's frame is updated
        [cellOne setNeedsLayout];
        [cellOne layoutIfNeeded];

        CGFloat heightOne = [cellOne.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
        return heightOne + 2;

    } else if ([model isKindOfClass:[D self]]) {

    // more code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this is a bug. The workaround to avoid the table jumping right after tapping a cell is to add:

```
[self.tableview reloadData];
```

in your table viewWillDisappear

https://devforums.apple.com/message/1050163#1050163

https://devforums.apple.com/message/1042398#1042398

Comment: Perfect!!  Thanks for pointing me to the Dev Forums links too.